# How to load Libraries in custom_loader?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to load libraries such as session, ftp and so on, from a custom loader located in /application/core/SACC_Loader.php

I have thus far tried the normal ways, and using get_instance() but to no avail.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class SACC_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    private $lang = null;
    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE, $ajax = FALSE)
    {
        /* Prepare default values always loaded unless it's an Ajax request */

        $vars = $this->static_content($vars);
        if($return){
            $content  = $this->view('components/header', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view('components/footer', $vars, $return);

            return $content;
        } else {
            $this->view('components/header', $vars);
            $this->view($template_name, $vars);
            $this->view('components/footer', $vars);
        }
    }
```

Or am I approaching this all wrong? My thinking is to use the custom loader to always carry required data into whatever controller is running without having to load a model in each controller, as I already use a custom loader for all pages to load a template instead of just a singular/multiple views per controller method.

I mean that works, but it feels repetative.

Comment: This kind of logic is more suited for a core `controller`. thus all your controllers would extend it. the loader class rarely needs to be fooled with.

Comment: Now that you mention it, that's acctualy brillant. And quite obvious, but I learned something so that's always good. Thanks for your insight and help!